# Java JAX-RS react on ANY endpoint invocation

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have a class implementing a JAX-RS endpoint, as per below:

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
@Path("/site/")
public class ApiSiteResource extends AbstractContentResource {
...
   @GET
    @Path("/article/")
    public Map<String, Object> getArticle (@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse reponse, @BeanParam ApiParams params) {
//do stuff
}

  @GET
    @Path("/category/")
    public Map<String, Object> getCategory (@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse reponse, @BeanParam ApiParams params) {
//do stuff
}
```

What I need is to perform common processing (for example, capture analytics data) when any of the endponts of the above REST class is invoked, e.g., both for /site/article/ and /site/category/. I'm ideally looking for a solution that would be invoked at the end of the method execution, and ideally with least possible change to the existing methods code, so adding another method call at the end of the method is not the best option as that leads to too much code coupling. Ideally, I would like processing to be fired from an external class.

Is there a way how that could be done?

Comment: try removing the forward slash after each route. As in `/site,  /article , /category `

Comment: Thanks Young, that is a good suggestion - but afraid it won't help the problem I'm trying to solve?

Comment: Okay if I get you, you are trying to call a method from another class?

Comment: The main idea is to call a method no matter which end point is invoked. Ideally I'd like to do so from a different class. The idea is to somehow inverse control and intercept the very fact that a method of the ApiSiteResource class is invoked so I could do required processing. If it's a method within the ApiSiteResource class itself, so be it, I just need a "catch it all" mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a method of the Resource class that is annotated with the @Context Annotation *and* has a parameter that is injected from the context scope.

```
  /**
   * This method is called by JAX-RS for each request before 
   * the identified resource method is invoked, since it is 
   * annotated with the Context Annotation and carries a 
   * context-scope parameter which is injected.
   */
  @Context
  public void setServletContext( ServletContext servletContext ) {
     ...
  }
```

(If you remove the ServletContext parameter, the automatic invocation on each resource call vanishes - at least in Jersey.)
Furthermore, you can put this method in a base class, say `DefaultResourceImpl`, which your Resource classes can extend, so you have this for all your Resource classes.

Comment: That is exactly what I've been looking for, thanks a million! It may not  quite fit my application and I'll have to scrap the whole idea in the end, but good to know it's there when I need it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JAX-RS Filters and Interceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html)

For example there exist Request filters and response filters. You may do some stuff there:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class PoweredByResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {

            responseContext.getHeaders().add("X-Powered-By", "Jersey :-)");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I've stumbled upon later on, too, thanks for a good example. Is there a filter that is executed after an JAX-RS method call (or how to make a filter trigger after the method call)?

Comment: Not clear why you want to do that after the method call? One request is one method call so instead of doing something upon exiting the method call, why not use the response filter (it will be triggered everytime before the response gets to the output stream). But if you really want something to happen on specific method calls you may use AOP (Spring AOP for example).

Comment: Well, the method that processes the REST end point retrieves required entities from the DB, so I need to collect those first and only then trigger the mechanism to do this extra work. So, I need the mechanism to be triggered at the end of the method call. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your useful replies and comments.

Actually, capturing analytics was just half the story. In fact, I've also needed to add response headers.

So, I ended up implementing a filter as below:

```
public class ApiResourceHeadersFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    public ApiResourceHeadersFilter() {
    }

    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET OPTIONS");

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Plus added a mapping in the web.xml:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>ApiResourceHeadersFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.workangel.eap.filters.ApiResourceHeadersFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ApiResourceHeadersFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/site/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Works like a charm; no messy code dependencies or modification. I'm sure I can extend it further should I need to collect analytics data as well.